# What is the best way to process an array to Pluck off the Year to Render in a React Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have an array of data that I want to use to render in a `stateful React Component`. It has a property on it called `creation_date` that I want to pluck the year off of.

Here is my `archives.js` file

```js
const archives = {
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Employee Engagement Summary",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2018",
                "date_range": "03/01/2018-05/15/2018",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 1",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2017",
                "date_range": "03/01/2017-05/15/2017",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 2",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2016",
                "date_range": "03/01/2016-05/15/2016",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2015",
                "date_range": "03/01/2015-05/15/2015",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2014",
                "date_range": "03/01/2014-05/15/2014",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2013",
                "date_range": "03/01/2013-05/15/2013",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2012",
                "date_range": "03/01/2012-05/15/2012",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        }
    ]
};

export default archives;
```

Then I want to take that year `array` and render it in my `component`.

```html
<ul>
  <li>2018</li>
  <li>2017</li>
  <li>2016</li>
  <li>2015</li>
  <li>2014</li>
  <li>2013</li>
  <li>2012</li>
</ul>
```

Now I started my component here is what I have thus far:
Here is my ArchivesSearchList.js file

```js
import React from "react";
import {archives} from "../../mocks";

class ArchivesSearchListContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = {          
          archiveYear: ""
      }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => { 
    this.getArchiveYear()
  }

  getArchiveYear = () => {
    const archiveYear = archives.data.map((data) => {
      return data.attributes.creation_date.match((/\d{4}/)[0]);
    });
    this.setState(() => ({
      archiveYear: archiveYear
    })); 
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ArchivesSearchListContainer;
```

Comment: if the range is 03/01/2011-05/15/2014, do we need to pluck 2011, 2012,2013 and 2014?

Comment: @sumit actually I just want to take the year from the `creation_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the year part from you creation_date, you can use something like this:

```
your_object.creation_date.split(", ")[0]; // creation_date lets say is "March 21, 2016"
```

The output will be "March 21".

To remove everything else other than year part, use can do it in the following way:

```
your_object.creation_date.split(", ")[1];
```

The output will be 2016.

Also, in your getArchiveYear method, you are using array.map function which returns an array. You need to loop through that array to show the output.

```
getArchiveYear = () => {
const archiveYear = archives.data.map((data) => {
  return data.attributes.creation_date.split(", ")[1];
});
this.setState(() => ({
  archiveYear: archiveYear
})); 
}
```

Comment: I am glad that my answer was helpful. Please mark as answer if this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: This is ugly way, we can use date time functions

Comment: that makes the date format depend heavily on how dates are saved on server side as Javascript's Date() function converts the dates into user's local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using getFullyear()

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp

```js
const archives = {
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Employee Engagement Summary",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2018",
                "date_range": "03/01/2018-05/15/2018",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 1",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2017",
                "date_range": "03/01/2017-05/15/2017",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 2",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2016",
                "date_range": "03/01/2016-05/15/2016",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2015",
                "date_range": "03/01/2015-05/15/2015",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2014",
                "date_range": "03/01/2014-05/15/2014",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2013",
                "date_range": "03/01/2013-05/15/2013",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "archive",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sample Survey 3",
                "description": "Report description goes here",
                "creation_date": "March 21, 2012",
                "date_range": "03/01/2012-05/15/2012",
                "data_sets": "Facility A, Nursing Department"
            }
        }
    ]
};

let arr=archives.data.map(a=>new Date(a.attributes.creation_date).getFullYear());
console.log(arr);
```